# Classical Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization produces large backward error

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

Consider the vectors $u$ and $v$ given by$$u=(1,1)/\sqrt{2}$$ and $$v=(1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon).$$ The Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization will consist of projection $$\hat{v}=v-(u^Tv)u$$ and consequent normalization $$\tilde{v}=\hat{v}/||\hat{v}||_2.$$ Prove the following conjectures:

**Conjecture 1**: Use $$fl(u^Tv)=\sum_{i=1}^2u_iv_i(1+2\delta_i)$$ to arrive at $$\hat{v}_j=(v_j(1+\delta_j)-\sum_{i=1}^2(u_i(1+2\hat{\delta}_i)v_i(1+\delta_i))u_j(1+2\hat{\delta}_j)$$ and $$\hat{v}_j=(v_j-\sum_{i=1}^2(u_iv_i)u_j)(1+C\bar{\delta})$$ where C is bounded by entries of $u$ and $v$

**Conjecture 2**: Use $$fl(u^Tv)=\sum_{i=1}^2u_iv_i(1+2\sigma_i)$$ to arrive at $$fl(||v||_2)=||v||_2(1+\tilde{C}\delta)$$ if $\hat{v}=v(1+C\delta)$ where C is bounded by entries of $u$ and $v$

**Conjecture 3**: Use Conjecture 1 and 2 to show that when $\epsilon$ is small, the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization results in a large backward error

Any ideas on how to proceed?

---

**Edit** : So here's what happens when you start plugging stuff in and foiling it out. The intuition into coming up with the right formulation is still not clicking but it does say to use "empirical" estimates. I'm still not sure why we need the particular values of u and v for the formulation in conjectures 1 and 2.

$$\hat{v}=v-(u^Tv)u=(1+\epsilon,1-\epsilon)-\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=(\epsilon,-\epsilon)$$ and $$\tilde{v}=\frac{\hat{v}}{||\hat{v}||}=\frac{(\epsilon,-\epsilon)}{\sqrt{2}\epsilon}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$

but

$$fl(u^Tv)=\sum_{i=1}^2u_iv_i(1+2\delta_i)=u_1v_1(1+2\delta_1)+u_2v_2(1+2\delta_2) \\=\frac{1+\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}(1+2\delta_1)+\frac{1-\epsilon}{\sqrt{2}}(1+2\delta_2)$$

So I'm confused as to what I'm supposed to do with $\hat{v}$ and $\tilde{v}$ for the floating point arithmetic part. I mean it's obvious as to why we get those roundoff error expressions, which are added for each algebraic operation(I'm still not sure how they get a 2 in front of delta for some of them), but it makes sense overall.

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to proceed? Without that, no one knows where to start when trying to help you and the question will probably be ignored or down voted..

Comment: I was gonna plug and chug and see if that reveals anything. Don't want to put that down though

Comment: By plug and chug I mean substitution and expand

Comment: well, I guess I'll post what I derived since no one is saying nothing

Comment: Might be too many questions too, puts people off. Try just Conj 1. You have several undefined symbols too like $fl$ and $\delta$

Comment: The notation is standard and appropriate for the tags numerical-methods and numerical linear algebra. fl$(x)$ is the standard notation for the floating point representation of the real number $x$. In the context of error analysis, small Greek letters traditionally denote rounding errors bounded by the unit roundoff. This is also the case for this question. I agree that OP should add some independent work.

Comment: Just added some independent work to my post. I hope it shows where I'm conceptually not understanding the problem